# Installing MS Web Deploy 3.0 - Failed to start WMService

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008, webdeploy

I have a dedicated server and I am trying to install MS Web Deploy 3 using the Web Platform Installer running as administrator.

It fails to install with the message:

```
We're sorry. The following products have failed to install.
**Web Deploy 3.0 - July 2012**
This product did not install successfully: Service 'Web Management Service' (WMSvc)
failed to start.  
Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services.
```

I have tried running the installer using 'Run As Administrator' but this error comes up each time.  Does any one know how I can verify or fix this issue?

Thanks!  Sorry for any noobness!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a possible answer to this as I wouldn't give up. go to your iis installation and select the server so you get the options, go to management service.  you can try checking "Remote Connections" and restarting if that doesn't help, select the certificate you have installed in the ssl certificate dropdown.  I was able to install the web deploy software after this.

Comment: Had same problem.  Went to IIS Management Service section and found I had to select and SSL Certificate there so the service could start.

Comment: Windows Server 2012 IIS8 - this worked for me as well.  Thank you.

Comment: Selecting the SSL certificate fixed the problem for me, as well. Thanks!

Comment: If you have not removed the WMSVC Certificate, first remove it intentionally and then create another one with the same name. this solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Having the same problem. Seems to be a problem with Web Deploy v3. I installed Web Deploy v2 without problems. It looks like they both can coexist. Just make sure to change the path for the Web Deploy Agent Service from C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3 to C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2

Answer (score 1):

I also found a possible answer to this issue. It seems that WebPI doesn't install the IIS Management Service as a dependency for Web Deploy.

After installing IIS Management Service (and re-installing Web Deploy) it began working.